# Is Lax-Miligram theorem a generalization of Riesz representation?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H$ a hilbert space with inner product $\left<.,.\right>$. We denote $\|\cdot \|$ the norm induced by the inner product. Lax-miligram tels us that there is a one-to-one correspondance between Continuous and elliptic bilinear form $a:H\times H\to \mathbb R$ and continuous linear functional $L:H\to \mathbb R$. I.e. that if $a$ is continuous (i.e. $a(u,v)\leq K\|u\|\|v\|$), elliptic (i.e. $a(u,u)\geq C\|u\|^2$) and if $L$ is a $L:H\to \mathbb R$ is continuous an linear, then there is a unique $u\in H$ s.t. for all $v\in H$, $$a(u,v)=L(v).$$

Is this a sort of generalization of Riezs representation theorem ? Because it looks very similar, but a bit more general.

Comment: Yes, it is basically a non-symmetric version of Riezs' theorem.

Answer (score 1):

It is the other way around, in my opinion.

One usually applies the Riesz operator (From Riesz' theorem) in your Hilbert space to show Lax-Milgram. Idea:

- Seeking solution to $Ax = f$, A being strongly positive and bounded.
- There is a bijective mapping,  *I*, by Riesz.
- Define $ \phi (x) = x + \tau I(f-Ax)$
- Show that $\phi$ is a contraction, and Banachs Fixed Point Theorem yields Lax-Milgram.